# Use Progress Bar according to file size

Tags: asp.net

I am using upload file and want to show progress bar according to the file size.

I don't know how to use progress bar that work according to the file size.

```
<script language='Javascript' type="text/javascript">

  function addFile() {

        var ni = document.getElementById("fileDiv");

        var objFileCount = document.getElementById("fileCount");
        var num = (document.getElementById("fileCount").value - 1) + 2;
        objFileCount.value = num;
        var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
        var newdiv1 = document.createElement("div");
        var divIdName = "file" + num + "Div";
        newdiv.setAttribute("id", divIdName);
        newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment"/><a href="#" onclick="javascript:removeFile(' + divIdName + ');">Remove </a>';
        ni.appendChild(newdiv);

  }

  function removeFile(divName) {
        var d = document.getElementById("fileDiv");
  d.removeChild(divName);

}

</script>

<div>
     <input type="file" name="attachment" runat="server" id="attachment" onchange="document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink').style.display = 'block';" />
      <input type="file" name="attachment" runat="server" id="File1" visible="false"/>
     <div id="process" style="height:10px; width:150px; background-color:Gray"></div>
  <input type="hidden" value="0" id="fileCount" />
  <div id="fileDiv">
  </div>
  <div id="moreUploadsLink" style="display: none">
        <a href="javascript:addFile();">Attach another File</a>
  </div>
  <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpFileCollection uploadFiles = Request.Files;
    for (int i = 0; i < uploadFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile uploadFile = uploadFiles[i];
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName);
        if (fileName.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            uploadFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Others/") + fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

When first time page is loading it's showing one file upload control with upload button.

When i am selecting one file after that one anchor button is appears with name attach another file.

When i am clicking on that again another file upload control is appears.

Just like Gmail you might have seen.

Now i added one div id is progress just below the file upload control and i want when they click on attach file so with every file upload control progress bar should show just like Gmail.

I don't want any jQuery codes

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why can't you use jquery? 

If that's really 100$ not an option you may take a look at the code suggested below and port to pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting solution http://www.ultramegatech.com/2010/10/create-an-upload-progress-bar-with-php-and-jquery/

For something fast and easy, use http://www.uploadify.com/

Here is another common method, but, again, your server needs APC http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/